# Is it "where is my wife and kids" or "where are my wife and kids"?

Tags: grammar

Is it

> where is my wife and kids?

or

> where are my wife and kids?

If the answer is "where is my wife and kids", what if I swap wife and kids and say "where is my kids and wife"? Would that still be correct?

Comment: This is elementary. The wife and children are more than one person, so _are_.

Comment: Which form is correct: Where **is** they (my wife ***and children***)? Or Where **are** they?

Comment: @KateBunting I saw someone who seemed like a native speaker commented "Where is your wife and kids" earlier on Twitter, so I was confused. That's why I came here to ask even though it might seem elementary to native speakers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Of course where ARE they is correct. However, after reading the answer I got, I learned that "where is my wife and kids" can also be perfectly acceptable in some regions.

Comment: Which regions? Which country? Where? Evidence? The accepted answer is nebulous and vague, and although it may be true that some native speakers use the singular verb when the subject is clearly plural,  you didn't ask if both forms were correct, you asked which one was.

Comment: I just wish learners would link and cite their sources IN the question and not in the comment section.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you want to know which regions and evidence. I suggest that you ask fertilizerspike directly. They're the one who said that and they know a lot more than I do. Have a nice day.

Comment: The poster on Twitter was probably just typing in haste and added 'and kids' as an afterthought.

Comment: It should be you wanting to know and asking, you are after all the OP. But I will ask because good answers provide supporting evidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are referring to two subjects,  "are" would be preferable, formally. However, common usage varies from place to place in natural speech.

Try breaking it into two sentences as follows:

"Where [x] my wife"

"Where [x] my kids"

Taken separately one would formally say:

"Where is my wife"

"Where are my kids"

Again, however, in some regions common usage suggests that "Where is my kids" would be informally acceptable and not unusual. In this case you could reasonably ask "where is my wife and kids".

Even in some regions where "where are my kids" is more commonly used, incomplete adherence to formal grammar might also make "where is my wife and kids" (or "where are my kids and wife") perfectly acceptable, and possibly preferable to "where is my kids and wife" (or "where are my wife and kids"). That is to say, in some regions it is common to set the verb to fit the plurality (or not) of the first subject, disregarding the second subject. To many people this sounds more correct, even though formallty it may be incorrect.

If that was confusing, welcome to American English.

But as you are asking about both "wife" and "kids", in order to be more generally conformist i would suggest using "are" in cases like this.

Comment: Can you provide any supporting evidence? Could you please specify in which regions of the US (I'm assuming your answer refers to it) do they use the singular verb when the [**the compound subject**](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/compound-subjects-and-verb-number)  is evidently plural

Comment: The further south you go the more common it is, like many other idioms

Comment: "Where is my wife and kids?" is not an idiom? An idiom would be: "feeling under the weather", and "cat got your tongue?". You say there are regions where it is common practice to match the verb only with the plurality of the first noun, irrespective of whether the second noun is singular. But surely it is perfectly correct to use a plural verb when the *compound subject* is in fact plural, i.e. *they* that stands for either "my wife and children" or "my children and wife“ (an unusual and unlikely phrasing but YMMV).  Are you saying this feature is  confined to American English only?

Comment: Yes it is rather idiomatic, in that it contrasts with formal grammar but is adopted widely in some regions. Remember that human language is a biological system so it trends toward efficiency in some unpredictable ways. I believe not just in America but English speakers in Europe sometimes have weird customs with verb tense, also.